# use a variable in other component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I need to call some variable in other component so i can use it in render with conditions (a global variable )

the first component code :

```
class Connexion extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // name: "",
          cnx_mail: '',
          cnx_pwd: '',
          items: [],
          errors: {},
          redirection : false,

          formErrors: {cnx_mail: '', cnx_pwd: ''},
          emailValid: false,
          passwordValid: false,
          formValid: false
        }

        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

    componentDidMount() { }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(`${API}/api/connexion`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
              },
            body: JSON.stringify ({
                email: this.state.cnx_mail,
                password: this.state.cnx_pwd,
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({ items: json.result });

            // console.log("jsooon: ", json);
            localStorage.setItem('head', json.result.split('.')[0]);
            localStorage.setItem('payload', json.result.split('.')[1]);
            localStorage.setItem('signature', json.result.split('.')[2]);

            var roole = JSON.parse(atob(json.result.split('.')[1])).account[0].role ;
            // this.setState({ therole : roole });
            if(roole=== 'admin') {
                console.log("role admin : " , roole);
                console.log(json.result);
                this.setState({ redirection: true })
                // this.context.router.push('/accounts');
                //   return <Redirect to='/accounts' />
                // this.props.history.push('/accounts')

            }
            else {
                console.log("is user");
            }
        })
    }
...
```

Here i have to get `"roole"` value and call it in another component in its `render()` and make a condition to say

if `roole=="admin"` display a `div1`, otherwise display `div2`

Comment: From what I understood, you must use [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: Can you also include code snippet of the component where you want to use it? Also, just to clarify, do you intend to redirect it through `react-router`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that variable to page where you want to redirect like this

```
this.props.history.push('/accounts', {roole})

// Access variable to redirected page
this.props.location.state.roole;`
```

Another way is you can store that role into local storage and access that value from local storage.

Comment: if you want to route another component this method is right one. if you are using in child component pass the variable as props.

Comment: Yeah..this is the basic concept of **React** that you can pass a parent component's variable to the child component as a '**props**.

Answer (score 0):

If the component you want to pass props, is a child to this one, you need to use props, to pass it down. 
Example:

```
<ChildComponent roole={this.roole}/>
```

In other cases, you need to use

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/your_path',
  state: { roole: this.roole }
})
```

To get it, use :

```
this.props.location.state.roole
```